# Dealing with "empty" anchor tags while using HashRouter from React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) and I've had some difficulty getting started with the BrowserRouter from `react-router-dom`. I opted to use the HashRouter instead and it works much better.

For context, I am building a note-taking application.

There are some instances where I have anchor tags like this:

```
// list of notes
notes.forEach(note => <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>{note.title}</a>);
```

However, when I'm on the `file:///home/grapefruit/my_app/src/index.html#/notes` route, clicking the anchor tag (with `href="#"`) obviously sends me back to the "root" route (`file:///home/grapefruit/my_app/src/index.html#/`).

I am looking for ways to prevent this from happening. The route should not change when the user chooses a note to view. Instead, the `onClick` handler changes the `activeNote` state, which determines the note to be shown in the right-hand pane.

I could do this (which does work), but instinctively it feels like a bad approach:

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
a.forEach((current) => current.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.preventDefault()));
```

I also wonder whether the anchor tag is semantically appropriate for this purpose. I am open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preventDefault` to prevent the default (redirect) behavior:

```
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // todo: do the onClick job
}

// ...

notes.forEach(note => <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>{note.title}</a>);

// Also, i think you should add key={some_unique_key} in above anchor tags
```